# Solving an AAA triangle using circles

Tags: geometry, triangles

I was asked to find the angles of an isosceles triangle by circumscribing a circle around it, then drawing another circle with the tip of the triangle as its center, and a radius of half of the leg. [image]

I can see that the ratio of AD to DE is the same as AB to BC, but how does this help me know the angles of the triangle? The lengths are 10 for the legs and 6 for the base. I know I can use other methods to find the angles, but how do I use this method - meaning, how can I specifically use the circles to find the angles? I know the radius of the upper circle to be $\frac{1}{2} AB$, and that $DE=\frac12 BC$.

Comment: I'm not sure what the circles are for; the angles at $B,C$ will obviously be $\cos^{-1}(3/10)$ and the angle at $A$ will be $2\sin^{-1}(3/10)$.

Comment: @Joffan I agree. I don't understand how the circles help.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Is this what they were asking for?

$\alpha = m \angle BAC = m \operatorname{arc} DE$

$\dfrac{\pi - \alpha}{2} = m \angle ABC = \dfrac 12(m \operatorname{arc} GE)$

\end{document}

Comment: It could very well be! Do you know of a way to take this farther? Meaning - how can I know the measure of arc GE?

Comment: @Burt From the picture, it's $\pi - \alpha$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint. In the upper circle you have the information you need to find the $\sin$ of half the central angle.

Comment: Because I know the radius length? How can I determine the length of the hypotenuse?

Comment: Is it half the length of BC? And then half of that again?

Comment: @Burt Because half that angle is in a right triangle two of whose sides you know.

Comment: But why draw circles? If all sides are known, sine and cosine can be calculated without additional construction

Comment: @Vasya agreed - this is why I have not yet accepted an answer